# how to redirect to a page from botton?

Tags: html, django

Hello i am newbie using DJANGO , i am trying that when i click on 'Continue' it redirects me to the template carrito.html but it aint working :/

```
//i've tried this

<a href="/base/carrito">Continue</a>

 // and i've tried this
<button type="button">
    <a href="{% url '/carrito/' %}">Comprar!</a>
</button>
```

i get this
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zcl4B.png)

the routes are plantilla/base/carrito.html

Comment: I suggest you to complete https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/. This is Django Docs introduction tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to navigate locally, you have to specify proper path based on your file location. If you are in same folder, you don't need to specify the path. Also, include .html at the end like this:

```
<a href="carrito.html">Continue</a>
```

Assuming you are in plantilla folder:

```html
<a href="base/carrito.html">Continue</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite an easy task, first you need to show your urls.py file. If for instance your urls.py file is like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('carrito/', views.carritoView, name="carrito"),
]
```

You will notice that my in my url patterns, it has an attribute called "name", this is what you will be needing to redirect to that page from wherever you are.

In your html templates, you can then do something like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'carrito' %}">Continue</a>
```

This would work perfectly.